# Figuring out what $\mathrm{O}(n)/\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, quotient-spaces

Just learned about quotient spaces using the definition $V/W:=\{x+W|x\in V\}$ where $W$ is a subspace of $V$. Came up with some examples to see how it was working, but couldn't figure out what $\mathrm{O}(n)/\mathrm{SO}(n)$ was, even for $n = 2$. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: You should be using the definition of a [quotient *group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group), not a [quotient vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: @angryavian Shouldn't both work though?

Comment: @NateStemen No, because $O(n)$ is not a vector space: it is not closed under scalar multiplication, let alone addition.  You can't say that $SO(n)$ is a subspace of $O(n)$ if neither is even a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint/Solution:**

Note that $det:O(n) \to \frac {\mathbb Z}{2 \mathbb Z}(=\{-1,1\}$) is a surjective group homomorphism.

What is the kernel of this map?